# Django Custom 404 errors

Tags: django, http-status-code-404

I have added a custom 404 template to my django site, the problem is you have to set `debugging` to `False` to make custom 404 template to load, so how is it possible to check the errors of the custom 404 itself?

Answer (score 0):

Well you could just make a new route e.g. `/404` and serve your custom 404
template there and check it for errors.

Comment: I was just about to answer the question myself, thanks for the answer